# Different TextView appearence in Activity and Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I have used a certain layout to `setContentView()` of an `Activity` and it works perfectly fine. But when I use this same layout in a `Fragment` there are a certain set of `TextView`s lose their text and I don't know why. The `Activity` and `Fragment` have similar sizes (roughly 90% of the height of the screen, 100% of width). Additionally - when I debug `getText()` for each of the `TextView`s in the keyboard of the `Fragment` the correct letters are returned.

[image: With Text - Activity]
[image: No Text - Fragment]

The two images uses the same layout to display the content (which leads me to believe the fault isn't there - feel free to correct me) but the fragment is contained within some extra layout to give the `Toolbar`. This is the code XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`R.layout.app_bar_main`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.apps4life.quoteunquote2.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <!-- Fragments go in here -->
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was much more simple. This code was present in both the `Activity` and the `Fragment`:

```
float keyWidth = keysArray[0].getWidth();
for(int a = 0; a < 27; a++){
    keysArray[a].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, keyWidth/2);
}
```

but it was in `OnWindowFocusChanged()` in the `Activity` and in `OnCreateView()` in the `Fragment`. This means that for the `Activity` the `keyWidth` was an appropriate size while for the `Fragment` it was 0 leading to a text size of 0.